# req.body me retorna un objeto vacio en post

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy haciendo una api con `nodejs` y cuando hago una peticion post a modo de prueba enviando una data cualquiera en postman, en consola me retorna un objeto vacio, todo esto al intentar imprimir `req.body` dentro de la funcion createUsers

```
const createUsers = async(req, res) => {
 console.log('recibe', req.body);
 res.send('user created');
}
```

Los middelawares utilizados:

```
// Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Cuando hago la peticion por postman:
[image]

Por otro lado, esto me retorna en consola lo que yo esperaba era que me retornara lo que se envia por postman:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes bien configurado el Postman y lo que mandas al servidor no se reconoce como un json. Para obtener el resultado deseado:

1. Selecciona `body`
2. Selecciona `raw`
3. Selecciona `JSON`
4. Respeta la estructura de un `JSON`. En la imagen que adjuntas NO cumples con la estructura. Las claves en un archivo `JSON` SIEMPRE van entre comillas dobles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si solucionas eso, obtendrás el resultado esperado.

Comment: Enorme! gracias!